# PDB SDO_GEORASTER ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: oracle

I am getting ORA-00902: invalid datatype when trying to create a table with the SDO_GEORASTER column in PDB, Oracle 23c.
I am using an [Oracle Database 23c (23.2.0) Free docker image](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md), leaving almost everything by default (specifying only ORACLE_PWD, port and data volume).
I am connecting using "system" login.

If I connect to CDB, using Service name = FREE - data type works.
If I connect to PDB, using Service name = FREEPDB1 - does not work.

If I select info about current database using query

```
select
  sys_context('USERENV','CON_NAME') CON_NAME,
  sys_context('USERENV','CON_ID') CON_ID,
  sys_context('USERENV','DB_NAME') DB_NAME
from DUAL
```

I am getting the following results:

```
Working database: CDB$ROOT; 1; FREE
"Broken" database: FREEPDB1; 3; FREEPDB1
```

Data types SDO_GEOMETRY and SDO_TOPO_GEOMETRY work properly in both databases.

What needs to be done to make it work in PDB?

Comment: Raised the issue on github: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/2654